# Use both images and other features for classification

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, keras

I want to do use both images and other features for classification of an image. I am using CNN for classifying images. But how do I integrate other features into my model?
Like if I am classifying an image the features I have are:

1.Images

2.Age

3.Sex

A naive approach would be:

```
x_combined = np.vstack((age_sex,x))
```

But then feeding x_combined to my CNN model will not help as these features are not part of images.

What I want to do is use both Age and Sex along with images for classification. I am using keras for creating my model. How to create my model ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very well stack other features with the pixel values. A good Conv net will learn patterns and better features from the input.

You can also try adding these features at the last layer of Conv net to get the output. Try experimenting with both.

Comment: The second method seems better. But how do I stack these age_sex to the output of Flatten() layer in my CNN?

Comment: You could use the [Concatenation layer](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) from Keras, giving as input the CNN's flattened features and the labels for age and gender. This could, then, be fed to a fully-connected layer to be optimized, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the second method that [@janu777](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8580478/janu777) suggested, you could train several CNNs considering different genders and age ranges (-10 years, 11-18, 19-30, 31-60, 61+). During testing, you just select the specific model for age and gender.

The rationale behind this if that data from different ages and genders may present different patterns that a specialized CNN could learn. In theory, a single CNN should be capable of learning all these patterns within the data, but that would require a huge ammount of training samples, which are not always available.

A great disadvantage of this idea is that you need data for every combination of gender/age you intend to train. Lack of representative data will probably make your model perform poorly.